# Add drop down select box to label class contact form

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

I'd like to be able to add a drop down select box to my contact form. Here's my existing html code for the field I wish to use:

```
<label class="topic">
<input type="text" name="topic" placeholder="Subject" value=""
data-constraints="@Required" />

<span class="empty-message">*This field is required.</span>
<span class="error-message">*This is not a valid subject.</span>
</label>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What's preventing you from adding a `select` element to this form?

Comment: is it what you want to do? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

Comment: Yes, that was the first thing I tried. I added the select code everywhere I could within my original code, but the form never rendered correctly.  It must have something to do with the CSS, but I don't know to troubleshoot that.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `<select>` tag.

```
<select>
 <option value="o1">Option 1</option>
 <option value="o1">Option 1</option>
 <option value="o1">Option 1</option>
</select>
```

More info: 
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

Comment: Yes, that was the first thing I tried.  I added the select code everywhere I could within my original code, but the form never rendered correctly.